# Animation appear on mousedown and disappear on mouse up

Tags: hide, show-hide, clickable, mousedown, mouseup

I'm really super new to jQuery and i'm trying to figure out how to make an animation or image appear when a person clicks and holds down and then disappears when they mouseup. I've sort of figured out how to do that with this code:

```
<script>
$( "#clicky" )
  .mousedown(function() {
      $( this ).html('<img src="images/Diana.gif" style="width:500px;"/>');
  })

  .mouseup(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
</script>
```

BUT the entire div disappears on mouseup! I'd like to make it so it's clickable over and over. Maybe I'm referring to the wrong thing? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example:

```js
$(document).on('mousedown',function(){
      $( "#clicky" ).show().html('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/2000px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" style="width:70px;"/>');
      })
     .on('mouseup',function() {
        $( "#clicky").hide();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clicky"></div>
```